# No Controller lifecycle methods in developer guide

Tags: sapui5

When I create an SAPUI5 project in Eclipse, I get all the lifecycle methods (onInit, onBeforeRendering, onAfterRendering, onExit) for a controller. However when I look at the controller code in the online [Developer Guide](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/50579ddf2c934ce789e056cfffe9efa9.html), I do not see any lifecycle methods, but only this method:

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("", {
   });
});
```

If I run this code in Eclipse, it works just fine.

This is confusing. Is it that from the version 1.38.7 of SAPUI5 the lifecycle methods have been dumped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to API reference 1.38.7 (top right corner) https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html

They are still there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But why this new sap.ui.define method instead of placing the code in any of the lifecycle methods which is usually done?

Comment: You still have all the lifecycle methods with the `sap.ui.define` syntax, they just haven't implemented it in the example yet -- except for `Component.js`, you generally don't need code in the `onInit` event hook of each controller anyway, but if you look at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2.html, there is the `onInit` event hook implemented in the Details controller

Comment: Thank you Ryan and Qualiture!